# Zonal Statistics R (raster/polygon)

Tags: r, statistics, polygon, raster, spatial

In R, there are deviations calculating the mean in function 'zonal.stats' of package 'spatialEco' compared to 'extract' in package 'raster'. For both I used a polygon as the zone field and a raster for the values.

Here is an example:

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
library(sp)

#Create raster
ras <- raster(nrows=100, ncols=80, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=800)
val <- runif(ncell(ras))
values(ras) <- val

#Create polygon within raster extent
xym <- cbind(runif(3,0,1000), runif(3,0,800))
p <- Polygons(list(Polygon(xym)),1)
sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(p))
spdf <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(sp, data=data.frame(1))

#z1 zonal statistics using "spatialECO"
z1 <- zonal.stats(spdf, ras, stats="mean")

#z2 zonal statistics using "raster"
z2 <- extract(ras, spdf, fun=mean)
```

What causes the deviation of z2 and z1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`spatialEco::zonal.stats` uses `exactextractr` (I have not checked the code, but it told me to install it to be able to use `zonal.stats`) which should be more exact if you are considering polygons (the raster package turns them into rasters first, see `zonal` below). However, the below example (it is only one case) suggest that spatialEco is less precise.

Example (avoid random numbers, but if you do use them, use `set.seed`). I start with very large grid cells.

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)

ras <- raster(nrows=4, ncols=4, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=800)
values(ras) <- 1:ncell(ras)
set.seed(1)
xy <- cbind(runif(3,0,1000), runif(3,0,800))
xy <- rbind(xy, xy[1,])
sp <- spPolygons(xy, attr=data.frame(x=1))


### zonal statistics using "spatialECO"
zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="mean")
#  mean.layer
#1          7
### zonal statistics using "raster"
extract(ras, sp, fun=mean)
#     [,1]
#[1,]    6
### same as 
# x <- rasterize(sp, ras)
# zonal(ras, x, "mean")
```

With raster you can also get a more precise estimate like this

```
e <- extract(ras, sp, weights=T)[[1]]
weighted.mean(e[,1], e[,2])
#[1] 5.269565
```

To see how many cells are used

```
zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="counter")
#  counter.layer
#1             6
extract(ras, sp, fun=function(x,...)length(x))
#     [,1]
#[1,]    3
```

One way to look at this is to create higher resolution raster data.

10x higher resolution, same values

```
ras <- disaggregate(ras, 10)
zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="mean")
#  mean.layer
#1        5.5
extract(ras, sp, fun=mean)
#         [,1]
#[1,] 5.245614

zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="counter")
#  counter.layer
#1           218
extract(ras, sp, fun=function(x,...)length(x))
#     [,1]
#[1,]  171
```

100x higher resolution, same values

```
ras <- disaggregate(ras, 10)
zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="mean")
#mean.layer
#1   5.299915
extract(ras, sp, small=TRUE, fun=mean)
#         [,1]
#[1,] 5.271039


zonal.stats(sp, ras, stats="counter")
# counter.layer
#1         17695

extract(ras, sp, fun=function(x,...)length(x))
#      [,1]
#[1,] 17289
```

At the highest resolution the mean values are similar (and the relative difference in the number of cells is small); but raster was closer to the correct value (whatever that is, exactly) at a lower resolution (and also with the weighted mean). That is unexpected.

For better speed, there is now also the `terra` package

```
library(terra)    
r <- rast(ras)
v <- vect(sp)
extract(r, v, "mean")    
#     ID    layer
#[1,]  1 5.271039
```

Answer (score 3):

Each algorithm is using a different number of pixels to calculate the zonal stats; thus, the difference is probably caused by that (z1 is higher than z2). According to this tiny example I would infer that `zonal.stats` is less restrictive than `extract`. Thus, probably `zonal.stats` takes into account every value of the raster that falls inside the polygon; however, `extract` only takes into account pixels whose center is found inside the polygon (check the function's documentation).

```
# Create a function to count the number of pixels used to calculate the zonal stats
counter <- function(x, na.rm = T) { 
  length(x)
} 

#z1 zonal statistics using "spatialECO"
z1 <- zonal.stats(spdf, ras, stats="counter")

#z2 zonal statistics using "raster"
z2 <- extract(ras, spdf, fun=counter)
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Indeed the 'extract' function provides some description in the documentation about how many pixel are chosen and gives some opportunities for modification. 'zonal.stats' remains a bit of a black box. I'll stick with 'extract' then (even though it is way slower..)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Robert Hijmans for your insights. Based on your example I've done some further comparisions of 1) precision and 2) computing time by calculating zonal means for different functions and resolutions:

```
library(raster)
library(spatialEco)
library(terra)
library(exactextractr)
library(sf)

ras <- raster(nrows=4, ncols=4, xmn=0, xmx=1000, ymn=0, ymx=800)
values(ras) <- 1:ncell(ras)
set.seed(1)
xy <- cbind(runif(3,0,1000), runif(3,0,800))
xy <- rbind(xy, xy[1,])
sp <- spPolygons(xy, attr=data.frame(x=1))

mn <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=6, nrow=4))
colnames(mn) <- c("disagr", "raster", "raster_weight", "spatialEco", "exactextractr", "terra")
mn[,1] <- c(2,10,50,250)
tm <- mn

for (i in 1:5){
  d <- mn[i,1]
  rasd <- disaggregate(ras, d)
  
  on <- Sys.time()
  mn[i,2] <- raster::extract(rasd, sp, fun=mean)
  off <- Sys.time()
  tm[i,2] <- off - on
  
  on <- Sys.time()
  mn[i,3] <- raster::extract(rasd, sp, fun=mean, weights=T)[[1]]
  off <- Sys.time()
  tm[i,3] <- off - on
  
  on <- Sys.time()
  mn[i,4] <- spatialEco::zonal.stats(sp, rasd, stats="mean")
  off <- Sys.time()
  tm[i,4] <- off - on
  
  on <- Sys.time()
  mn[i,5] <- exactextractr::exact_extract(rasd, st_as_sf(sp), fun="mean")
  off <- Sys.time()
  tm[i,5] <- off - on

  on <- Sys.time()
  val <- terra::extract(rast(rasd), vect(sp))
  mn[i,6] <- mean(val[,2])
  off <- Sys.time()
  tm[i,6] <- off - on
  print(i)
}
mn  # arithmetic mean
  disagr   raster raster_weight spatialEco exactextractr    terra
1      2 5.333333      5.269565   6.647059      5.271303 5.333333
2     10 5.245614      5.271039   5.500000      5.271303 5.245614
3     50 5.272370      5.271328   5.325525      5.271303 5.272370
4    250 5.271314      5.271303   5.282827      5.271303 5.271314
tm   # computing time in seconds
  disagr     raster raster_weight  spatialEco exactextractr       terra
1      2 0.03998685    0.03598809 0.003000021   0.002999067 0.008996964
2     10 0.09783196    0.04598618 0.003997803   0.003000021 0.008984089
3     50 0.37189507    0.40886688 0.004998922   0.003998041 0.021993160
4    250 4.10671687    8.29134583 0.035988092   0.019991875 0.336881876
```

Based on this example and when using polygons as zones `exact_extract` is the preferable choice.